# vuejs component load failures

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, asp.net-core-2.1

Using `vue ui` and the `inspect` task to verify the webpack.config.js, there are no errors reported upon completion, yet the app errors when bootstrapping. The load failure appears to be something other than location, the file is where it's expected.

#### console output

```
  [vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default: Error: Loading chunk home failed.
  (error: http://localhost:63660/wwwroot/dist/home.js) vue-router.esm.js:17:39

  [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation: vue-router.esm.js:17:39
  Error: "Loading chunk home failed.
  (error: http://localhost:63660/wwwroot/dist/home.js)"
  onScriptComplete http://localhost:63660/dist/main.js?v=u5nsel5s4jcTtEeZq4fdOeArMA_6XFxknkNJ6EByLqI:817:29
 vue-router.esm.js:1898:9

 Loading failed for the <script> with source 
 “http://localhost:63660/wwwroot/dist/home.js”. localhost:63660:1:1
```

#### web.config.js

```
  const bundleOutputDir = "./wwwroot/dist/";
```

The `output` config definition

```
   output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
        publicPath: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
    },
```

#### main.ts

The routes defined

```
   const routes = [
   {
    path: '/', name: 'home',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ './views/Home.vue'),
   },
   {
    path: '/fetchdata', name: 'fetchdata',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "fetchdata" */ './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.vue')},
   {
      path: '/about', name: 'about',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue'),
   },
  ];

 new Vue({
  router: new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes }),
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
 }).$mount('#app-root');
```

#### App.vue

```
  <template>
  <div id='app-root' class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <menu-component />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </template>

<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

  @Component({
    components: {
     MenuComponent: require('./components/navmenu/navmenu.vue'),
    },
  })

    export default class AppComponent extends Vue {
    }
  </script>
```

#### index.cshtml (app entry)

```
  @{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
  }

  <div id='app-root'>Loading...</div>

  @section scripts {
     <script src="~/dist/main.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
  }
```

#### package.json

```
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
  "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.2.0",
  "@vue/cli-service": "^3.2.0",
  "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
  "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
  "bootstrap": "^3.4.0",
  "css-loader": "^2.0.1",
  "eslint": "^5.11.0",
  "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
  "event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.5",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
  "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
  "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
  "jquery": "^3.1.1",
  "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
  "ts-loader": "^5.3.1",
  "typescript": "^3.0.0",
  "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
  "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
  "vue-loader": "^15.4.2",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
  "webpack": "^4.28.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
  "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.4.0",
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3"
},
"dependencies": {
  "vue": "^2.5.17",
  "vue-class-component": "^6.0.0",
  "vue-property-decorator": "^7.0.0",
  "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
  "vuex": "^3.0.1",
  "popper.js": "^1.14.6"
}
```

Comment: Try renaming `web.config.js` to [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bonehead error...the error output, as usual, had the answer in plain sight but I was distracted by too many new things to see it. The `publicPath` was set to the root, static directory (wwwroot/dist), so the url served was including `wwwroot`. The fix was to just specify `dist/` and not `wwwroot/dist //publicPath: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),`

```
   output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
        publicPath: "dist/",
        libraryExport: "default",
    },
```